# How to make zsh autocomplete failover to compdef _files

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, zsh-completion

I needed to get the fingerprint of a ssh key using:

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user.pub
```

after typing:`ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ss` <kbd>TAB</kbd> It was not giving any options.

I had to do:

```
$ compdef _files ssh-keygen
```

After that I was available to autocomplete using the files path, but the command autocomplete stop working, so if if I type `ssh-keygen -` <kbd>Tab</kbd> I don't see any more this output:

```
$ ssh-keygen -
 -- option --
-B  -- show the bubblebabble digest of key
-C  -- provide new comment
-D  -- download key stored in smartcard reader
-N  -- provide new passphrase
-P  -- provide old passphrase
-U  -- upload key to smartcard reader
-b  -- specify number of bits in key
-c  -- change comment in private and public key files
-e  -- export key to SECSH file format
-f  -- key file
-i  -- import key to OpenSSH format
-l  -- show fingerprint of key file
-p  -- change passphrase of private key file
-q  -- silence ssh-keygen
-t  -- specify the type of the key to create
-y  -- get public key from private key
```

So wondering if there is a way of having both options enabled so that I can do something like:

`ssh-keyg` <kbd>TAB</kbd> that will give me:

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

Then I can do

`$ ssh-keygen -` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

That would print the option menu and been available to do:

`$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ss` <kbd>TAB</kbd>

And have list of options what could work so at the end I would get something like:

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user.pub
```

For now I just add to my `~/.zshrc` this:

```
compdef _files ssh-keygen
compdef _files adb
compdef _files mysql
...
```

But I have to do that for avery command I want to use the _files completion, therefore I would like to know if there is a way to always use `_files` or failover to it.

Any ideas?

Could it be possible to make it behave like `csh` in where pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> shows files options?

**Update:**

I notice that if I the last argument is an `-f` the autocomplete works:

`ssh-keygen -l -f ~/.ssh`<kbd>TAB</kbd>

But for custom scripts, commands what function, widget alias could help do force the `_files` completion.?

Comment: "Could it be possible to make it behave like csh in where pressing Ctrl+d shows files options?" - I think you can achieve this using the example given in the [zsh docs for completion widgets](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Widget-Example-1)

Comment: I know this doesn't necessarily help you, but what you're after with ssh-keygen is exactly how my zsh behaves, so it's definitely possible. ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh<TAB> gives me a files completion list.

Comment: @NilsLuxton Hi, you can both get options ``ssh-keygen -``TAB and also get files  when doing ``ssh-keygen -lt ~/.s`` TAB,  if yes could you please tell me how you are doing it.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I don't know enough about how it all works to be able to tell you how to do it I'm afraid...sorry!

Comment: if you come back on IRC at #zsh we can try and figure it out together - I've found something I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update to `zsh` this is how I did it:

```
# check the zsh info
brew info zsh

# install zsh
brew install zsh

# add shell path
sudo vim /etc/shells

# add the following line into the very end of the file(/etc/shells)
/usr/local/bin/zsh

# change default shell
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

I had issues completing `git-flow` this was fixed by reinstalling with `--without-completions`:

```
$ brew install git --without-completions
```